# Downgrading Sharepoint Database from SQL2008 to SQL2005

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

Good day,

I have a request from a client to move the sharepoint 2007 from a server to another. The actual Sharepoint2007(WSS3.0) content databases are on SQL2008 but the new location only has access to a SQL2005. I did the SQL Downgrade procedure by exporting the data from the sQL2008 to SQL2005. I can browse the tables and query everything. When I attache it to SP2007 I get the operation successfull and when I get to Central Admin I can see the site in list site but it does not display the information (ex: URL, Site Admin, Content Database) and I can't browse the website either. Any Ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Using database export is not supported. The option here would be to use a 3rd party tool to perform a content migration.

It may or may not work, but you could also try a stsadm -o backup/restore operation.